# What is shared_ptr's aliasing constructor for?

Tags: c++, c++11

In this page (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/), paragraph 5, it says:

> Additionally, shared_ptr objects can share ownership over a pointer while at the same time pointing to another object. This ability is known as aliasing (see constructors), and is commonly used to point to member objects while owning the object they belong to. Because of this, a shared_ptr may relate to two pointers:
>
> - A stored pointer, which is the pointer it is said to point to, and the one it dereferences with operator*.
> - An owned pointer (possibly shared), which is the pointer the ownership group is in charge of deleting at some point, and for which it counts as a use.
>
> Generally, the stored pointer and the owned pointer refer to the same object, **but alias shared_ptr objects (those constructed with the alias constructor and their copies) may refer to different objects**.

Then I read this page (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) about the aliasing constructor of shared_ptr. But I still think this "aliasing" behavior confusing. **Why is it here? What is it for? In what situation would I want this feature?**

Comment: From your own quote: "[aliasing] is commonly used to point to member objects while owning the object they belong to."

Comment: you should be already familiar with aliasing because both C and C++ allow aliasing by default, even without considering `shared_ptr` you are already using a language which allows aliasing by default.

Comment: @hvd yes. I noticed this later after I posted this question. But it is still not specific enough.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Simple example:

```
struct Bar { 
    // some data that we want to point to
};

struct Foo {
    Bar bar;
};

shared_ptr<Foo> f = make_shared<Foo>(some, args, here);
shared_ptr<Bar> specific_data(f, &f->bar);

// ref count of the object pointed to by f is 2
f.reset();

// the Foo still exists (ref cnt == 1)
// so our Bar pointer is still valid, and we can use it for stuff
some_func_that_takes_bar(specific_data);
```

Aliasing is for when we really want to point to `Bar`, but we also don't want the `Foo` to get deleted out from under us.

---

As Johannes points out in the comments, there is a somewhat equivalent language feature:

```
Bar const& specific_data = Foo(...).bar;
Bar&& also_specific_data = Foo(...).bar;
```

We're taking a reference to a member of a temporary, but the temporary `Foo` is still kept alive as long as `specific_data` is. As with the `shared_ptr` example, what we have is a `Bar` whose lifetime is tied to a `Foo` - a `Foo` that we cannot access.

Comment: `but we also don't want the Foo to get deleted out from under us` that's a job for your `shared_ptr`, nothing really close to what the aliasing is for .

Comment: @user2485710 I think you're misunderstanding the question? The `shared_ptr<Bar>` I created is actually sharing ownership with the `shared_ptr<Foo>`. There's just one underlying object in all of this, but the aliasing constructor lets us have a `shared_ptr` that points to a member instead.

Comment: So, you mean in case you want to reset `f` but you don't want the object pointed by `f` destroyed because you're going to need its member object? Oh. Thanks a lot. I get it. q^.^p

Comment: So we could say that `specific_data` and `f` share the same resource, but the former's `operator->` actually gives you `bar` instead?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, exactly.

Comment: Perhaps you can compare this with `struct A { int x; }; const int& x = A().x;`. In this case, the `A` object is kept alive aswell as long as the reference `x` exists.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Quite an interesting [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35947296/2069064) to just that example...

Comment: Please bear in mind that `const` is necessary here. Regular reference won't extend temprorary's lifetime

Comment: @Barry Can you show possible implementation of this constructor?

Comment: Hi @Barry, I make [a similar test}(https://ideone.com/gr3ZSH), and seems that when I reset f, its `use_count` will be 0 rather than 1. Why this happen?