# How do you manage pointers to base classes that are both extended in a derived class?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Recently, I have been abstracting and cleaning up a project of mine to get it ready for new features. I came across a design problem when I realized that I wanted to manage pointers to a graphics context and a window as abstract classes. I have searched for answers but haven't found anything satisfying yet. I have a situation where I'm creating a window that extends the window class and the graphics context class like so...

```
class base_a
{
// base_a virtual methods
};

class base_b
{
// base_b virtual methods
};

class derived : public base_a, public base_b
{
//other methods
};

int main ()
{
    derived* d = new derived();
// This is what I want to do
    std::shared_ptr<base_a> ptr1 (d);
    std::shared_ptr<base_b> ptr2 (d);
}
```

While this more or less works during the lifetime of the object, it becomes a problem when destructing since depending on the order of destruction you are potentially deleting empty memory. It's useful to have the pointers to both as I need access to the virtual functions and I would like to keep the graphics context and the window decoupled if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: Changed `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` as the former was incorrect

Comment: Why not just `std::unique_ptr<derived> d { std::make_unique<derived>() };`?

You can then call methods from `base_a` and `base_b` like that: `d->baseAMethod()`, `d->baseBMethod()`

Comment: use `base_a* ptr1 (d); base_b* ptr1 (d);`?

Comment: @op414 That would work but I don't really want the code that deals with the graphics context to know anything about the window, since it is not guaranteed that the it will have a class that derives both. It might be what I end up doing though.  I might also make the graphics context a subclass of window, though that doesn't really line up with the idea of the graphics context being a feature of the window.

Comment: You can do this then:
`std::unique_ptr<derived> d { std::make_unique<derived>() }; base_a* ptr1 { static_cast<base_a>(d.get()) }; base_b* ptr2 { static_cast<base_b>(d.get()) };` you can then pass `ptr1` and `ptr2` to other functions/methods which only care about one interface. What is important is to have a single `std::unique_ptr` to manage the lifecycle of your object.

Comment: You can't have two `unique_ptr` to the same object.  This should have been obvious.  You can have two `shared_ptr` to the same object.  This should have been obvious.  What's less obvious is how to make two `shared_ptr` of different type to the same object that share a reference count, but `shared_ptr` is designed to allow that.  `shared_ptr` has support for pointers to subobjects keeping the complete object alive, and that support can be used for either base subobjects or member subobjects.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is true, however this is a bit of a weird case as they are pointers to to base classes. When I use a `unique_ptr`, this will point to the place within the derived class that the base class exist thus you can have unique pointers like that though it is obviously error prone. I did not know though that `shared_ptr` had that functionality. Is there anyway to prevent other classes from owning them i.e. enforcing something like a `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @JustinW: Just because the pointers compare unequal does not mean they are unique for the purposes of `unique_ptr`.  `unique_ptr` is one-per-object, and always points at the complete object that needs to be destroyed and deallocated when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.  The code in your question was already wrong when you made one `unique_ptr`, the second one was just piling on.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh ok I see. I will update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `shared_ptr` to manage ownership of the `derived` class. Then use `std::shared_ptr`'s [aliasing constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109379/what-is-shared-ptrs-aliasing-constructor-for) to share ownership of the `derived` instance through a pointer to one of the base classes. Here's what that might look like:

```
class base_a {
public:
    int x = 1;
};

class base_b {
public:
    int y = 2;
};

class derived : public base_a, public base_b {
public:
    int z = 3;
};

int main() {
    auto d_ptr = std::make_shared<derived>();
    
    auto a_ptr = std::shared_ptr<base_a>(d_ptr, static_cast<base_a*>(d_ptr.get()));
    auto b_ptr = std::shared_ptr<base_b>(d_ptr, static_cast<base_b*>(d_ptr.get()));
    ...
```

This provides safe access to the base classes without risking early or double deletion. Only when the last of all these pointers goes out of scope will the `derived` instance (and both of it base class objects) be destroyed.

```
std::cout << "x : " << d_ptr->x << '\n';
std::cout << "y : " << d_ptr->y << '\n';
std::cout << "z : " << d_ptr->z << '\n';

std::cout << "---\n";
a_ptr->x = 4;
b_ptr->y = 5;

std::cout << "x : " << d_ptr->x << '\n';
std::cout << "y : " << d_ptr->y << '\n';
std::cout << "z : " << d_ptr->z << '\n';
```

Output:

```
x : 1
y : 2
z : 3
---
x : 4
y : 5
z : 3
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddc55f1fed8c4aa5)</kbd>

---

**EDIT:** while the above holds true for member objects and base class sub-objects, `shared_ptr` already defines conversions for base class pointers, as was kindly pointed out by @BenVoigt. This simplifies the code to:

```
auto d_ptr = std::make_shared<derived>();

auto a_ptr = std::shared_ptr<base_a>(d_ptr);
auto b_ptr = std::shared_ptr<base_b>(d_ptr);
```

<kbd>[Updated Live Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afbb4354f3a65101)</kbd>

Comment: This isn't wrong, but `shared_ptr` defines conversions that will set up the link for you in the case of base subobjects.  You'd have to do exactly this in the case of member subobjects.