# What happens when we reset a shared_ptr when there are other shared_ptr alias constructed from it?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am currently learning `shared_ptr`'s alias constructor, and I wrote code like this

```
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<Father> father = std::make_shared<Father>();
    std::shared_ptr<Son> son(father, &father->son);
    printf("%d\n", father.use_count());
    printf("%d\n", son.use_count());
    father.reset();
    printf("%d\n", father.use_count());
    printf("%d\n", son.use_count());
    printf("%d\n", father.owner_before(son));
    printf("%d\n", son.owner_before(father));
    return 0;
}
```

And it prints out

```
2
2
0
1
1
0
```

And I got lost here. In my opinion, after `father.reset()`, `father` should still have `use_count = 1` rather than 0, because son is alias constructed from father, and it not destructed. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109379/what-is-shared-ptrs-aliasing-constructor-for), the author also says `father.use_count()` is 1.

> // the Foo still exists (ref cnt == 1)
> // so our Bar pointer is still valid, and we can use it for stuff

So why `printf("%d\n", father.use_count());` prints out to be 0?

Comment: *"From this post, the author also says father.use_count() is 1"* - No such thing is said there. You confusion stems from bad naming. You conflate the pointers with the objects they manage.

Comment: He says "the Foo still exists (ref cnt == 1)"

Comment: Yes, **the Foo**. He does not say the `use_count` of a reset pointer still magically refers to an objects it was told to forget about.

Comment: OK, so as soon as `shared_ptr` is reset, it has no way to access `Foo`. So is there any other ways that I can check Foo still exists? For example, trace `Foo::~Foo`?

Comment: Yes. Tracing a d'tor will tell you when the object goes away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `father.reset()`, `father` doesn't point to anything. It holds a null value (officially "there is no managed object").

You are printing the `use_count` of nothing, not the `use_count` of the `Father` or `Son` object, and [the `use_count` of a null pointer is 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count).