# C++ | Return reference to vector of shared_ptrs casted to derived type

Tags: c++, std, game-engine, game-development

I've been trying to implement my own entity component system in C++ and altough I'm quite new to this programming language, I've been quite satisfied.
However, I've recently run in a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I've created an `unordered map`, in which I'm storing the `type_index` of my components as *Key*, and a `vector` of `shared_ptr`s to the components of that type as *Value*; however, since my components are all different structs, I am storing them using the shared pointer to their base class (`IComponent`).

I now want to be able to the get the vector of the corrent component type, by passing the `type_index` of the component I want, to a function which gets it from the `unordered_map`. But here's the problem: since I've stored the pointers as `IComponent`, when returning them from the `GetComponents` function, I cannot use them as the correct type. So I tried casting each element, but by doing this I've returned the reference to a new `vector` which is NOT stored in the `unordered_map`, and so when I modify this `vector` in some other part of my code, the changes will not be saved.

Here are some code snippets:

ComponentManager:

```
// an unordered map which stores the component types and their vectors
// key: the component's type index
// value: the vector containing the shared pointers of the components of that type_index
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEComponent>>> components_map;

// create a new component and assign an entity id
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> CreateComponent(const UUID& e_id) {
    // get the type_index using the type_info from the generic T type
    // (the type_info is returned by the typeid(T) operator)
    std::type_index type_idx = std::type_index(typeid(T));
    // check if the given key exists in the component container
    // if it doesn't exist, create it
    if (components_map.find(type_idx) == components_map.end()) {
        // log the new component type info
        TraceLog(LOG_INFO,
            "COMPONENT_MANAGER: Added new type_idx to the components map. [%s]",
            type_idx.name()
        );
        // save the new type_index to the map with an empty vector as value
        components_map.emplace(type_idx, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEComponent>>());
    }
    // create a new T component shared pointer
    std::shared_ptr<T> component = std::make_shared<T>();
    // assign an entity id
    component->e_id = e_id;
    // get the current components_of_type using the type_index
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEComponent>>& components_of_type = GetBaseComponents(type_idx);
    // add the new component to the vector
    components_of_type.push_back(component);
    // return the component
    return component;
}
```

What I want to accomplish:

```
    for (std::shared_ptr<ECPosition> pos : ComponentManager::GetComponents<ECPosition>()) {
        TraceLog(LOG_INFO, "x is: %f y is: %f", pos->x, pos->y);
    }
```

Comment: There's no inheritance relationship between `std::shared_ptr<IEComponent>` and `std::shared_ptr<ECPosition>`; there isn't a inheritance relationship between `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ECPosition>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEComponent>>` either, so you simply cannot turn one into the other and keep the original one modifiable. A way you could return a reference to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ECPosition>>` would be to use `std::variant<std::monostate, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ECPosition>>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<OtherSubclass>>, ...>` as value type in the map

Comment: do you know if there are any better ways to store components in an ecs system? I know something similar to what I'm trying to do is possible since I've seen for example in bevy (a rust game framework) but I don't know where I can find more information as to how they've implemented their system

Comment: You can `reinterpret_cast` the whole vector, but don't tell anyone https://godbolt.org/z/obabdcM1M

Comment: Not sure I get the problem right, but maybe those two pieces of advice will be helpful:  1. How about using a vector of reference wrappers? https://godbolt.org/z/Wsax49hMo
2. Have you considered returning a vector of aliased shared ptr's? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109379/what-is-shared-ptrs-aliasing-constructor-for

Comment: @Osyotr is that bad practice? it seems like the easiest solution currently

Comment: @NicolaPicarella tricking type system is indeed a bad practice. I personally would write something like `template<class T, class Fn> ComponentManager::ForEachComponent(Fn && fn) { ...; for (auto && component : component) fn(std::static_pointer_cast<T>(component)); }`

Comment: Another way is to write `template<T> T & As() { return static_cast<T>(*this); }` in `IEComponent`, and call it in your for loop.

Comment: @Osyotr why the double & symbol after Fn type in the function parameter? I know it means that it's an rvalue reference, but wouldn't just using "Fn" work?

Comment: @NicolaPicarella it's not an rvalue reference, it's [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)